# postgresql: delete rows in a table, that match values in another table via foreign key

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: `event_to_state_groups` and `events`

I can select all entries I want to delete in `event_to_state_groups` by

```
SELECT events.event_id, room_id, sender 
FROM event_to_state_groups, events
WHERE event_to_state_groups.event_id = events.event_id 
  AND events.room_id like '%jGUBNvBzjGyQyKKMJV:matrix.org'
```

How do I delete all those entries from the `event_to_state_groups` table that are connected to room_id `%jGUBNvBzjGyQyKKMJV%` in the `events` table ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
   delete FROM events using event_to_state_groups 
    WHERE event_id=event_to_state_groups.event_id AND room_id like '%jGUBNvBzjGyQyKKMJV%'
```

Comment: same error. maybe ecause i use "SELECT * FROM" instead of "DELETE FROM"? I first want to check, if those are the correctly selected events

Comment: yes select * from doesn't work with using ,remove using if you want to use select statement

Comment: so please add a SELECT command example, how to check first if you are going to delete the right bunch of data

Comment: select *  FROM events inner join event_to_state_groups 
    on event_id=event_to_state_groups.event_id AND room_id like '%jGUBNvBzjGyQyKKMJV%'

Comment: `»event_id« is ambicious`. also, I think you mixed up, what I want to delete. I want to delete entries in `event_to_state_groups` not in `events`

Comment: maybe `DELETE 
    FROM event_to_state_groups USING events
    WHERE event_to_state_groups.event_id = events.event_id 
    AND room_id = '$ROOMID'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delete from event_to_state_groups where room_id 
  IN (select e.room_id from event_to_state_groups e 
      INNER JOIN events ev on e.event_id = ev.event_id 
      WHERE e.room_id ilike '%jGUBNvBzjGyQyKKMJV%')
```

Comment: seems wrong: because room_id is in `events` not in `event_to_state_groups`